# Check if record exists, and find out which column(s) has changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a procedure that has the following code:

```
INSERT INTO DON_RECIP_RELATION (NUMBER, ID) 
  SELECT DISTINCT (rec.NUMBER), cur_ID
  FROM REC rec, DON don
  WHERE don.NUMBER = rec.NUMBER
  ...;
```

This works fine on an insert. But if I try to update an existing record, I get an exception saying: `ORA-00001: unique constraint` on the primary key, which is the ID.

I figured I have to make a check if the record already exists, then make an update on the specified column. But the table has like 30 columns or more, and while writing the sql code, I don't know which column the user is trying to alter. How can I do this. Say there is a column called `NAME`, and I know that's the column the user is trying to change, then I can do something like:

```
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID=cur_ID)
BEGIN
   UPDATE TABLE SET NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE ...) WHERE ID=cur_ID;
END
```

And I need to merge the `IF/WHEN EXISTS` with the `INSERT`, but I'm a little lost, as I'm still new to SQL.

PS. The cur_ID is a parameter give to the procedure, and it comes from the user (an a`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "spUpdateDonRecipRelation"(cur_ID IN NUMBER)`

Comment: Have you looked at the MERGE command?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows. `SELECT DISTINCT (rec.NUMBER), cur_ID` is better written as `SELECT DISTINCT rec.NUMBER, cur_ID`, but can also be written as `SELECT DISTINCT rec.NUMBER, (cur_ID)`... i.e. the parentheses make no difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can still get duplicates from the `select`.  The `distinct` does not prevent this.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT MAX(rec.NUMBER), cur_ID
FROM REC rec JOIN
     DON don
     ON don.NUMBER = rec.NUMBER
GROUP BY cur_id;
```

Then, you can put the check in a `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO DON_RECIP_RELATION (NUMBER, ID) 
    SELECT MAX(rec.NUMBER), don.cur_ID
    FROM REC rec JOIN
         DON don
         ON don.NUMBER = rec.NUMBER
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DON_RECIP_RELATION drr WHERE drr.ID= don.cur_ID)
    GROUP BY don.cur_id;
```

(I am guessing that `cur_id` comes from the `don` table.)

Comment: Why do you write 1 in the subquery select? Is it just an example, or has it got a meaning?

Comment: `exists` and `not exists` subqueries are only evaluated based on the *rows* returned, not the columns.  I find "1" to be both easy to type and unambiguous.  In particular, I deplore `select NULL` in this case, because I don't like `NULL` meaning that something exists.

Comment: I never thought the solution would be so simple. Thanks